# Complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

What's the complexity of func1 if func2 = O(n) and func3 = O(n^2) ?

```
void func1 (int n) {
    int i, j, k;
    for (k=0;k<n;k++)          // O(n)
        printf("%d",k);
    i=0;
    while (i<2*n) {         // O(n)
        for (j=i;j>1;j--)   // Not executed
            for (k=15;k>0;k--)
                func2(n);
        for (j=n;j>1;j--)  // O(n)
            func3(n);      // O(n^2)
        i++;
    }
}
```

So that's O(n^2)O(n)O(n) + O(n) = max(O(n^4),O(n)) = O(n^4) ?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: I got O(n^4) since func2 is not beeing executed and func3 is under two loops: the most intern from 2 to n and the other from 0 to 2n-1.

Comment: `printf("%d", k)` is O(log(k)), not O(1), which makes the first loop O(log(n!)) = O(n log n), although that doesn't make any difference to the overall complexity of func1 this time, since that first loop is dominated by the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void func1 (int n) {
  int i, j, k;
  for (k=0;k<n;k++)       
      printf("%d",k);
  i=0;
  while (i<2*n) {             // O(2*n) = O(n)
    for (j=i;j>1;j--)           // O(n)
        for (k=15;k>0;k--)        // O(15) = O(1)
            func2(n);               // O(n)
    for (j=n;j>1;j--)           // O(n) 
        func3(n);                 // O(n^2)
    i++;
  }
}
```

For sequences, find the maximum of the steps.

As a rule of thumb, nested loops multiply, but you may need to examine the ranges carefully if they are not independent make sure this is the case (see Paul's comment for an example).

Comment: O(n^2)O(n) O(n) = O(n^4)? The book awnser was O(n^3)

Comment: Really?which book?@TrapezeraBuscand and how does that book explains its result?

Comment: The complexity of nested loops don't multiply in general, although that pseudo-method happens to give the right result here. For example, if you replaced `i=0` with `i=1` and `i++` with `i*=2`, the calculations for total cost of func2 is O(n^2) even though the outer loop runs `O(log n)` times.

Comment: @PaulHankin I have clarified the answer. Can you explain your example? It doesn't seem immediately obvious to me why the runtime for func2 would'nt be O(n^2 log n) in your case.

Comment: @StefanHaustein Because the `j` loop runs `i` times and not `n`. Then (assuming n is a power of 2 for simplicity) func2 is called 15*(1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + n) = 15*(2n) = 30n times, so the complexity is O(n^2). In general, you can multiply nested loops if their ranges are independent, but in the specific cases (eg: i=1...n, j=1..i) it happens to work because sum(i for i=1..n) = n(n+1)/2 = O(n^2).